# Anaconda failing to import a program despite egg in site packages

Tags: python, plugins, installation, anaconda

Hi I ran a standard install https://github.com/madmaze/python-tesseract, which did indeed copy the egg to my site packages. However when I run conda list the package isn't there. I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Conda doesn't know about packages that you install manually, but if you run `python` and import the package, it should be able to find it.

Comment: i am afraid this is problem I was trying to explain. An anaconda install is my default python as per path variable, and a library I have install does have an egg in the anaconda site packages, but when I run python import library, it can't find it

Comment: specifically the library in the original post